# Is there a way to know what virtual Keycodes are available on current computer

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

I'm trying to find a way to know all characters that are directly inputable by the user on its current keyboard, using modifiers, or not.

I think `UCKeyTranslate` is the function I need to call. But I think I also need a way to find all available `virtualKeyCode` on the current physical keyboard.

Thanks.

Comment: The computer could have more than one physical keyboard attached, or possibly none.  I suspect that a solution may involve querying the IO Registry.